# XML Doc in JSP with sessionvariables

Tags: xml, string, jsp, session-variables

I have a JSP page where I am trying to display a Session Variable that is a string in XML format.  I am attempting to do this by setting the contentType to text/xml but the solution to my problem seems to not be that simple.  The String will show up as plain text.  Here's the small code snipp:

```
    <%@ page language="java" contentType="text/xml; charset=ISO-8859-1"
pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<webiDocument>
<% Object xml = session.getAttribute("XMLstring");
    String XML = xml.toString();%>
<%= XML %>
</webiDocument>
```

of course only the  tag is showing up as XML, I can't get the session variable to display the same way.  I'm guessing I have to go a whole new route with this page.  Any ideas?

Comment: Although this is a poor approach, this should work. Are you sure that the attribute value is not just an empty string? Are you sure that the attribute has initially been set with the proper value? Do a `System.out.println("XML string: " + xml);` right after you retrieve the attribute and then read the server log for that line if it indeed prints the expected data.

Comment: Having re-read the question once more, I find that the *"The String will show up as plain text."* is ambiguous. Can you elaborate in more detail? E.g. by including the obtained page source (rightclick, view source) or some screenshot in the question.

Answer (score 0):

if your problem is that the session variable is not displayed, even though it is set properly from the above code,, then try modifying the above code by directly getting the session variable as a String(by type casting) instead of creating a Object and then converting as given below,, works well for me,,

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/xml; charset=ISO-8859-1"
pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<webiDocument>
<%     String XML = (String)session.getAttribute("XMLstring");
%>

<%= XML %>
</webiDocument>
```

Getting the following on client:

```
<webiDocument>null</webiDocument>
```

as the session variable is null for me,, if you have initialized properly then this might work

Comment: That really doesn't make any difference. It's only a *bit* better (more NPE-safe) approach.

Comment: ya,, but the given code doesnt do even this correctly,, think the question is not clear a bit,, needs clarification,,